# How to filter text data containing key words from an unnamed column excel with python pandas and print to txt file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, txt

Im pretty new to this so please bear with me.

I have an excel sheet that contains certain text strings i would like to extract and copy to a text file - i have been doing this manually for a long time and im sick of it.

So my plan was to write a script that would extract this data from the excel sheet and create a txt file.

This is how far i have gotten:

```
#EXTRACT CLIPID FROM XCEL SHEET
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import Tk     # from tkinter import Tk for Python 3.x
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

Tk().withdraw() 
filename = askopenfilename()
data = pd.read_excel (filename)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df)
```

The data i want is located in column A1, but is not always in the same row.
There are 3 separate keywords i want to look for:

1. "POP"
2. "TVS"
3. "PLANET"

The strings look something like this:

Channel2021_1_DRU_POP_15s_16062021
Channel2021_2_FANT_POP_15s_16062021
Channel2021_3_ITA_POP_15s_16062021

Channel2021_1_DRU_TVS_15s_16062021
Channel2021_2_FANT_TVS_15s_16062021
Channel2021_3_ITA_TVS_15s_16062021

Channel2021_1_DRU_PLANET_15s_16062021
Channel2021_2_FANT_PLANET_15s_16062021
Channel2021_3_ITA_PLANET_15s_16062021

This is the form of the extracted data i would like to write in a txt file.

So in essence i want to search column A1 for strings containing POP and print, then strings containing TVS and print, and lastly strings containing PLANET and print.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Dusan

PS:
Here is the output of `df`:

```
                                         Unnamed: 0  ...                                        Unnamed: 16
0                                               NaN  ...                                                NaN
1                                               NaN  ...                                                NaN
2                                       Spot 1 15 s  ...                                                NaN
3                                               NaN  ...                                        Indicazioni
4                                         106290.01  ...                        dire tutto + grafica ITALIA
5                                         138575.01  ...                                                NaN
6                                         142956.01  ...                                                NaN
7                                          85146.01  ...                                                NaN
8      Eurospin2021_16bis_1_POP_ITA_15s_24_06_2021   ...                                                NaN
9       Eurospin2021_16bis_1_TVS_ITA_15s_24_06_2021  ...                                                NaN
10   Eurospin2021_16bis_1_PLANET_ITA_15s_24_06_2021  ...                                                NaN
11                                              NaN  ...                                                NaN
12                                              NaN  ...                                                NaN
13                                      Spot 2 15 s  ...                                                NaN
14                                              NaN  ...                                        Indicazioni
15                                        164171.01  ...                       dire tutto +  grafica ITALIA
16                                       9003309.01  ...                                                NaN
17                                         88310.01  ...                                                NaN
18      Eurospin2021_16bis_2_POP_ITA_15s_24_06_2021  ...                                                NaN
19      Eurospin2021_16bis_2_TVS_ITA_15s_24_06_2021  ...                                                NaN
20   Eurospin2021_16bis_2_PLANET_ITA_15s_24_06_2021  ...                                                NaN
21                                              NaN  ...                                                NaN
22                                              NaN  ...                                                NaN
23                                      Spot 3 15 s  ...                                                NaN
24                                              NaN  ...                                         Istruzione
25                                        800214.01  ...  dire tutto + dire al kg dopo il prezzo per la ...
26                                       9001392.01  ...                                                NaN
27                                       9002306.01  ...                                                NaN
28                                        147804.01  ...                                                NaN
29     Eurospin2021_16bis_3_POP_DRUZ_15s_24_06_2021  ...                                                NaN
30     Eurospin2021_16bis_3_TVS_DRUZ_15s_24_06_2021  ...                                                NaN
31  Eurospin2021_16bis_3_PLANET_DRUZ_15s_24_06_2021  ...                                                NaN

[32 rows x 17 columns]
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of what `df` looks like after reading your file?

Comment: I'm new to the Excel thing as well. My reason for looking into it also was doing the same copy/paste everytime ;) For me this was an easy module to use, maybe you can look into this one as well: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: I am adding the output of df to my original post, as it is too long to post in a comment. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a proposal if you're still looking for a solution:

Withe sample frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    0: [
        'Channel2021_1_DRU_POP_15s_16062021',
        'Channel2021_2_FANT_POP_15s_16062021',
        'Channel2021_3_ITA_POP_15s_16062021',
        1.,
        2.,
        'Channel2021_1_DRU_TVS_15s_16062021',
        'Channel2021_2_FANT_TVS_15s_16062021',
        'Channel2021_3_ITA_TVS_15s_16062021',
        3.,
        4.,
        'Channel2021_1_DRU_PLANET_15s_16062021',
        'Channel2021_2_FANT_PLANET_15s_16062021',
        'Channel2021_3_ITA_PLANET_15s_16062021',
        5.
    ],
    1: '...',
})
```

```
                                         0    1
0       Channel2021_1_DRU_POP_15s_16062021  ...
1      Channel2021_2_FANT_POP_15s_16062021  ...
2       Channel2021_3_ITA_POP_15s_16062021  ...
3                                        1  ...
4                                        2  ...
5       Channel2021_1_DRU_TVS_15s_16062021  ...
6      Channel2021_2_FANT_TVS_15s_16062021  ...
7       Channel2021_3_ITA_TVS_15s_16062021  ...
8                                        3  ...
9                                        4  ...
10   Channel2021_1_DRU_PLANET_15s_16062021  ...
11  Channel2021_2_FANT_PLANET_15s_16062021  ...
12   Channel2021_3_ITA_PLANET_15s_16062021  ...
13                                       5  ...
```

this

```
selection = df.iloc[:, 0].str.contains(r'POP|TVS|PLANET', na=False)
print(df.iloc[:, 0][selection])
df.iloc[:, 0][selection].to_csv('items.txt', index=False, header=False)
```

prints you the desired entries

```
0         Channel2021_1_DRU_POP_15s_16062021
1        Channel2021_2_FANT_POP_15s_16062021
2         Channel2021_3_ITA_POP_15s_16062021
5         Channel2021_1_DRU_TVS_15s_16062021
6        Channel2021_2_FANT_TVS_15s_16062021
7         Channel2021_3_ITA_TVS_15s_16062021
10     Channel2021_1_DRU_PLANET_15s_16062021
11    Channel2021_2_FANT_PLANET_15s_16062021
12     Channel2021_3_ITA_PLANET_15s_16062021
```

and writes them into a file `items.txt`

```
Channel2021_1_DRU_POP_15s_16062021
Channel2021_2_FANT_POP_15s_16062021
Channel2021_3_ITA_POP_15s_16062021
Channel2021_1_DRU_TVS_15s_16062021
Channel2021_2_FANT_TVS_15s_16062021
Channel2021_3_ITA_TVS_15s_16062021
Channel2021_1_DRU_PLANET_15s_16062021
Channel2021_2_FANT_PLANET_15s_16062021
Channel2021_3_ITA_PLANET_15s_16062021
```

Since I'm unsure about the column names I have only used the index base selection (`.iloc`).

If you want the results in the order you've given then this

```
df = pd.concat([
         df.iloc[:, 0][df.iloc[:, 0].str.contains(tag, na=False)]
         for tag in ('POP', 'TVS', 'PLANET')
     ])
```

should work (just print `df` afterwards or write it to a file).

Btw.: This is too complicated

```
data = pd.read_excel (filename)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

You only need `pd.read_excel`:

```
df = pd.read_excel(filename)
```

**EDIT**:
Regarding the comments:

```
with open('items.txt', 'wt') as file:
    file.write('The following has been sent:')
    for tag in ('POP', 'TVS', 'PLANET'):
        file.write(f'\n{tag}:\n')
        items = df.iloc[:, 0][df.iloc[:, 0].str.contains(tag, na=False)].to_list()
        file.write('\n'.join(items))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, ill give this a try shortly! Thank you!

Comment: I works! Now i just have to tinker with it to get some custom predefined lines of text in between the different tag outputs when i print! Thank you very very much!

Comment: @DJ85 Nice. Depending on how complex the added "in between"-tasks are, you might want to consider leaving Pandas after retrieving the search results and doing it in pure Python (just dump the results in a list: `df.iloc[:, 0][selection].to_list()`). Pandas is a great tool but can sometimes lead to clumsy code. Not saying you should, just a consideration!

Comment: Well, i tried with pandas and failed - had to take an aspirin form my python headache... I wanted to have something like this: "The following has been sent: /n POP /n list items containing POP/n TVS/n list items containing TVS etc. Ill give it another go with to_list!

Comment: i get this error with to_list: KeyError: "None of [Index(['Eurospin2021_16bis_1_POP_ITA_15s_24_06_2021 ',\n       'Eurospin2021_16bis_2_POP_ITA_15s_24_06_2021',\n       ..........      dtype='object')] are in the [index]"

Comment: @DJ85 I've added some code that does something like you're describing. Maybe it fits your needs...

Comment: You are a saint sir! It works a treat! Thank you very much